# Datadog deployment through ArgoCD

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci-runner, datadog, argocd, terraform-provider-datadog

We have been deploying datadog agent and datadog cluster agent using helm through our gitlab-runner pipeline.

We want to incorporate datadog related deployment through ArgoCD. Could someone help us how can we create an application.yaml for datadog because through helm the files are deployment files.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment of Helm charts has in-built support with ArgoCD. You can deploy an ArgoCD application with a Helm chart and custom Helm values like so:

```
argocd app set <helm-chart> --values values.yaml
```

The [ArgoCD docs](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/helm/) has an end to end guide on how you can deploy Helm charts. It also includes a sample application.yml that you can copy.